# Drawing on WPF with System.Drawing.Graphics?

Tags: wpf, drawing

I'm making a game in WPF in which I need to be able to use the drawing functions in System.Drawing.Graphics. I looked into the `OnRender` function, but that only has a DrawingContext object, which is *not* what I need.

So, is there some control in WPF that I can place on my WPF Window that has an `OnPaint` (or something similar) event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `WindowsFormsHost` to host a Win Forms Control with OnPaint overrided