# Possibility of showing System.Drawing.Graphics object in a WPF control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

I'm using PrintDocument to print a receipt in for a POS system. I'm using the PrintPage event handler's graphics object to do the printing. The application is written using WPF with .NET 7.

It would be good if I could show a preview in the WPF application before printing. Is there any possibility to display a System.Drawing.Graphics object in a user control? If I could, I can re-use the same logic.

Comment: You may host a WinForms control: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6240267/1136211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot display a `System.Drawing.Graphics` object directly. What you can do is draw to a bitmap with [Graphics.FromImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and [display the bitmap in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap).

Something like:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(512, 512);
using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)){
   // Do drawing
}

var bitmapSource = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
   bitmap.GetHbitmap(), // you will need to delete this hbitmap
   IntPtr.Zero, 
   System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, 
   BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(512, 512));
```